# Domino designer view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I want in view display records only from 1 form, it's possible to block all other records from  other forms and display for example only from "Products" form records ?

Second question is how to hide empty recprds ? I want if all view fields is empty I don't want show this record in view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a select formula to view

```
SELECT Form="Products" & !(Field1 = "" & Field2 = "" & Field3 = "")
```

[image]

Look here for more information about [Selecting which documents display in a view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_PROGRAMMING_WHICH_DOCUMENTS_DISPLAY_IN_A_VIEW.html)